# How do i use Hypnotoad as a http server

Tags: perl, web, mojolicious

I am trying to use hypnotoad server to serve some static html pages. What configuration do i need to do or where shall i keep my static html files for hypnotoad to pick them.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIRC the servers provided by [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us), of which Hypnotoad is one, serve static HTML from a folder named `public`. All you should need is the most basic of applications to start the server. I this should be enough for simple use,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# needed to setup the usual index.html landing
any '/' => sub {
  shift->render_static('index.html');
};

app->start;
```

and run with `hypnotoad myapp.pl` (assuming this script is saved as `myapp.pl` and is in the same location as the `public` folder).